# best component(e.g. image control,canvas,rectangle etc) for sending color from one page to another page

Tags: windows-phone

Which is the best component(e.g. image control,canvas,rectangle etc) for sending color from one page to another page.(exclude Isolated Storage) in windows phone 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can send colors as anavigation parameter between pages . i can not understand your question